# How to get total number of records sql daily

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am currently doing to get the count,

```
Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE ATTEMPT_DATE='01/JUNE/19';
Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE ATTEMPT_DATE='02/JUNE/19';
.
.
Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE ATTEMPT_DATE='30/JUNE/19';
```

Is there any way to get all the SUM of ( count(*) all dates)

Comment: What is the type of the `ATTEMPT_DATE` column?  Is it text?

Comment: use `count` + `group by`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select ATTEMPT_DATE, count(*)
from MyTable
group by ATTEMPT_DATE;
```

If you want to counts dates within a range, use `where`:

```
select count(*)
from MyTable
where ATTEMPT_DATE in ('01/JUNE/19', . . . '30/JUNE/19');
```

You are using a non-standard date format.  If this were a standard date format (or if the column really is a date/datetime value), then I would suggest inequalities rather than `in`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use direct count(*)

```
Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE ATTEMPT_DATE BETWEEN '01/JUNE/19' AND '30/JUNE/19'
```

for datewise count use group by

```
Select ATTEMPT_DATE, count(*) from MyTable 
WHERE ATTEMPT_DATE BETWEEN '01/JUNE/19' AND '30/JUNE/19' group by ATTEMPT_DATE
```

Cheers!!

Comment: It was unclear **Is there any way to get all the SUM of ( count(*) all dates)** so given both the examples now